# How can I add an image saved locally to a plotly graphic in python?

Tags: python, image, plotly

I'm using plotly and would like to add a logo in my graphic. My layout term looks like this

```
layout = go.Layout(
    images=[dict(
        source="logo.png",
        xref="paper", yref="paper",
        x=0, y=0,
        sizex=10, sizey=10,
        xanchor="right", yanchor="bottom"
      )],
    height=1400, width=1100,
    hovermode='closest',
    title='fancy title',

    xaxis = dict(
     range = [10, 15],
     title = "xtitle",
     ticklen = 4,
     showgrid = False
    ),
    yaxis = dict(
     range = [20, 30],
     title = "ytitle",
     ticklen = 4,
     showgrid = False
   )
```

and although I don't get any error messages, my logo also doesn't appear anywhere in the resulting html file. The logo.png is saved in the same directory as the Python script used to generate the plotly html file. Reading up on the documentation of plotly, it seems you'd need to have a URL as source, not a local directory. Is there any way I can include the logo, which I have locally, without uploading it somewhere?

Addition: I tinkered around with dataURI encoding. I don't really understand how that works, I have to say, and I don't see any difference in the result. I tried

```
import base64
encoded = base64.b64encode(open("logo.png", "rb").read())
```

and then

```
images=[dict(
    source=encoded_image,
    xref="paper", yref="paper",
    x=8, y=50,
    sizex=100, sizey=100,
    xanchor="right", yanchor="bottom"
  )]
```

in the layout portion to no effect. I read online something like this should work. I toyed around a bit with PIL Image but with the same lack of results.

Comment: Have you tried to use the plotly.offline? It generates a local url page so you might can save it.

Comment: My whole code uses plotly offline. I haven't upgraded to the newst version, where it seems offline is default, because there seems to be little documentation out there for that.

Comment: If you use notebook, init_notebook_mode() and plotly.offline.plot(fig, filename='gauge-meter-chart.html') will open a new web for the plot graph.

Comment: I'm not planning to use notebook. Thanks for the suggestion, if nothing else works might have to try it.